# Implode comma in the i-th row of two-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

The array `$solution` is two-dimensional. I need to save its content to SQL table. However, before saving, I need to check that `$solution[i][0]` belongs to the result of the query `SELECT num_arr FROM Schedule WHERE num_arr<>''`.

The problem is with the line `$vals = implode(...)`. How do I implode comma in the i-th row of the array `$solution`? Now this line results in the string `0,0,0,0` instead of correct values.

```
    $columns_land = array("`num_arr`","`start`","`fin`","`way`");
    $cols_land = implode(",",$columns_land);

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($solution); $i++) {
            $vals = implode(',', array_map('implode_comma', $solution[$i]));
            query_land = "INSERT INTO `Sequence` (" . $cols_land . ") 
                          VALUES " . $vals . " 
                          WHERE num_arr='".$solution[$i][0]."' 
                          AND num_arr IN (SELECT num_arr FROM Schedule WHERE num_arr<>'')";

            $result_land = execute_query($query_land);
    }

    function implode_comma($arr) {
        return '(' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
    }
```

Comment: in implode_comma function, try getting output before returning it using temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

This statement has me confused:

```
$vals = implode(',', array_map('implode_comma', $solution[$i]));
```

Since `implode_comma()` expects an array, each item in `$solution[$i]` must also be an array; but that means `$solutions` itself must be a three-dimensional array.

I think you can just write this inside your loop instead:

```
$vals = implode(',', $solution[$i]);
$query_land = "INSERT INTO `Sequence` ($cols_land) 
    VALUES ($vals)
    WHERE num_arr='".$solution[$i][0]."' 
    AND num_arr IN (SELECT num_arr FROM Schedule WHERE num_arr<>'')";

$result_land = execute_query($query_land);
```

Btw, you should properly escape the variables you use in SQL, but I can't tell which database layer you're using, so I leave that up to you.

Comment: If I use $vals = implode(',', $solution[$i]);, then I get unquoted values: VALUES (BT01451087,2012-08-29 15:47,2012-08-29 16:10,1).

Comment: @youkuper that's because your original code didn't quote those values either :) like I said, I don't know what db API you're using